# How can I create a dictionary and output values using user input?

Tags: python, dictionary, output, user-input

I want to make a dictionary and then use user input to print the value of the key

Edit: I'm using Python 3.4.4
And thanks to the user who corrected grammatical and syntactical errors

*I tried to use the -input()- but with no luck
*I found this code:

```
usrInp = 'z' #default value z so that while works first time
exDict = {}  #initializing empty dict

while usrInp == 'z':
    key = input('enter key : ')
    val = input('enter val : ')
    exDict[key] = val
    usrInp = input('Enter z to continue adding, else any input to exit : ')

print(exDict)
```

But it is not what I want. My goal is to do something like this:

```
 dictionary{
     1:"Number one"
     2:"Number two"
     3:"Number three"
}

#Asking for user input code here

print() #Print the value of the key here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dictionary={
 "1":"Number one"
 "2":"Number two"
 "3":"Number three"}

x = raw_input()
print dictionary[str(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## try this

```
    usrInp = 'z' #default value z so that while works first time
    exDict = {}  #initializing empty dict
    while usrInp == 'z':
        key = input('enter key : ')) 
        val = input('enter val : ')) 
        exDict[key] = val
        usrInp = input('Enter z to continue adding, else any input to exit : ')
    
    print(exDict)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this code already works without the conversion